# How to show a linked page as the content of a table <td> element in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have made a HTML table.

Suppose I have a link, for example, link to **www.nokia.com** , can I show the linked page as a content of the table  element **when "click me" has clicked**? and how to do that?

```
<a href="#">click me</a>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
         // how to show the content of "www.nokia.com" page here
    </td>
  </tr>  
<table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use `<iframe>` and some jQuery for the job.

Example:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
      $("iframe").show();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">click me</a>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <iframe src="http://www.nokia.com" width="100%" height="300"  style="display: none;">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
      </iframe>        
    </td>
  </tr>  
<table>
```